# How can I call viewDidLoad in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, viewdidload

My code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class CellOneViewController: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var new1: UILabel!

let ref = Firebase(url: "https://burning-heat-8250.firebaseio.com/slide2")

    func viewdidload() {
        ref.observeEventType (.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        self.new1.text = snapshot.value as? String
    })
    }
}
```

I've read around that you can't call viewDidLoad in a UITableViewCell, only in a UITableViewController. All the answers are in Objective-C, but I'm writing the app in Swift. I don't receive any critical errors but when running the app nothing appears in the cell where the label is. I'm fairly new to using Xcode, as I am just going around following guides so if I'm saying something incorrect let me know.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think, you need method  func layoutSubviews().

Only ViewController gets func viewDidLoad() called, after view is loaded.

If you need to initialize something or update views, you need to do in layoutSubviews(). As soon, your view or UITableViewCell gets loaded, layoutSubviews() get called.

Replace viewDidLoad with layoutSubviews()

```
class CellOneViewController: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var new1: UILabel!

let ref = Firebase(url: "https://burning-heat-8250.firebaseio.com/slide2")

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    ref.observeEventType (.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.new1.text = snapshot.value as? String
           })
       }
 }
```

Comment: Generally `viewDidLoad` is only called once after initialization but `layoutSubviews` will be called whenever this cell appears, which makes it more like `viewDidAppear`. Starting observing might be OK, but still not ideal usage.

Comment: Yes, Will need to add a bool flag, to make it execute only once.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do this is that a `UITableViewCell` isn't a subclass of  UIViewController.

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/) is where you should set up your cells. You probably only want to do something like this in your custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
class CellOne: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var new1: UILabel!
}
```

Then in your TableViewController's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (provided you have imported firebase) you should dequeue a reusable cell, cast it as a CellOne (`as! cellOne`) and then you can set the `new1.text` value. I don't know what your reuse identifier is, but it would look something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Your-Reuse-Identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellOne
    cell.new1.text = "Your Value"
    return cell
}
```